# what pattern can i used between singleton or factory pattern in YuGiOh game?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm trying to develop simple game YuGiOh based on console. I've made Supercard which will inherite into 3 classes  trapcard, magiccard and monstercard. But I should add some pattern in that game, what is the best choice between Singleton and Factory Pattern.

and where should I put the pattern in my game?

Comment: If coder wants to implement design pattern then coder should know as many design pattern as possible. "Head First Design pattern" is recommended. Choosing between two depends on the scenario you are in. Both are having different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You question is far too vague for anyone to be able to help you, the Singleton and Factory patterns have quite different uses, and it may be that you can use both of them somewhere in you app.

Don't worry about patterns during the initial stages of your design, figure out in your own mind how you want things to work, maybe draw a few diagrams, think about what classes you will need and produce a high-level OO design. Patterns will come later and, generally speaking if you have gone through the steps outlined above it should be clear which (if any) patterns you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton pattern are for single instances objects. Factory pattern are for creating different instances of a super class or object.

The Singleton pattern is  applicable to the game itself and object managers (graphics object instance or any rendering object, sound manager, game manager, logic manager, etc.)

Factory pattern is usable when shuffling the deck or any other object generation mechanism. Possibly AI moves, etc.

There are a lot of other patterns that can be used for event chaining, for the AI, for dialog events and others.

codebox is right though, you need some sort of diagram to at least detail the game properly. Maybe you should start with that. (Creating a class diagram and sequence diagram will work for YuGiOh)

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you want. Singleton instances will be unique throughout your program, you will be able for example to have one single trapcard which will be shared by all the other objects in your program. If you just want a way to create the good card's instance, you may prefer the factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking "where to put my pattern" and "should it be factory or singleton" you should rethink your approach. In general patterns are designed and implemented to solve common problems met during software development. You dont use them without purpose before these problems appear.

I have no idea what is YuGiOh, but from your description and if you really want to use these patterns (i. e. educational purposes) I would use Factory to build these card objects, and singleton to implement some logging mechanism, but then again - as stated above your question is way to vague.